# Is there a single word to describe the function of magnets?

Tags: verbs

> A metal plate is attracted and stuck to a magnet.

I am trying to rewrite this such that a magnet is the subject. My example is as follows:

> A magnet attracts and holds a metal plate.

Is there a single word equivalent in meaning to "attract and hold"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magnets commonly either **attract** or **pull** objects. They can also **repel/repulse** objects. Small ones can **stick** to objects.

I think that the function of holding isn't that a magnet actually has, a magnet keeps pulling or attracting objects continuously even when they are already stuck to it.

In my opinion the use of either word is more than enough to describe what a magnet does.